# Im getting errors on line 1, about the () brackets and the , comma. I have already declared the enum values

Tags: java, android, random

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    GuideView whichView = GuideView.values()[which]; 
    switch (whichView) {
        case GuideView.Easy:
            R.integer.dif = 3;
            break;
        case GuideView.Medium:
            R.integer.dif = 10;
            break;
        case GuideView.Hard:
            R.integer.dif = 15;
            break;
    }
}
```

cant seem to figure this out, im getting errors on line 1 about the comma and the opening/closing brackets.

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: this line looks wrong `GuideView whichView = GuideView.values()[which]; `  Is GuideView really a static?

Comment: syntax error on token "(",";" expected

Comment: @ScaryWombat Could be an Enum

Comment: can you please post the error so that we can see where the error is and what exactly it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess at this point, would be that because the values() method is actually added by the compiler, not inherited in the normal sense, 
see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

The compiler does not like you directly using the output as an array. I have often seen this lookup done using:

```
static {... }
```

will allow you to create static lookup method within the enum which has the id as a parameter.

Comment: I am also unsure if the android Java has values() added at compile time, I have made the assumption here, and if your IDE has also made the assumption, I don't expect there is much wrong, but occam's razor holds.

Comment: thanks, that seemed to fix it.